# C: what is the result of I and ^ operation on char?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

There is a piece of code:

```
int p(char *a, char*b)
{
  while (*a | *b) 
  {
   if (*a ^ *b)
    //...
  }
}
```

and I don't really know what it's doing.

Edit: I understand what the `|` and `^` operators do, I just don't know what they'll do with `char` values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It treats them as small integers. The | operator then does an OR and the ^ operator does an XOR (exclusive or), on the individual bits making up the integers. Neither operation is particularly useful for most character-based applications, but they can be used (for example) to add a parity bit to a char in comms programming.

Comment: Fun with ascii :
#define TO_UPPER(ch) (ch) & ~0x20
#define TO_LOWER(ch) (ch) | 0x20

Comment: They don't work. TO_LOWER for example turns the NUL character into a space.

Answer (score 8):

While the string a or string b have not run out of characters, check to see if they are different.

```
int p(char *a, char*b)
{
     // While both string a and string b have characters left
     // note this assumes they are both zero terminated
     // and if not the same length they have trail zeros
     while (*a|*b)  
     {
         // check to see if the character is different
         // this is done via the xor
         if (*a^*b)
              //(...)
         }

         // should increment pointers or will never exit the loop
         // a++;
         // b++;
      }
```

Comment: ok but what is the exact result of *a|*b? does just do a bitwise operation on two binary numbers that represent the chars?

Comment: Hoping, of course, that there are some ++'s missing in the copied code.

Comment: @agnieszka *a|*b it just means a != '\0' && b != '\0'

Comment: wow just noticed I missed the questions point in title vs context of body

Comment: *a | *b doesn't assume that both of the strings have characters left.  It assumes that at least one of them (appear to) have characters left.

Using *a ^ *b for "are they different" obfuscates and is a poor choice of operator when != would work just as well and make intent clear.

Answer (score 3):

`|` is the bitwise OR operator. `^` is the bitwise XOR operator:

```
    10101010      11010101  
  | 01010100    ^ 11111110
  ==========    ==========
    11111110      00101011
```

While `char` can be used to represent characters, it's inherently an integer data type. It stores a binary number (just like everything else in a binary digital computer).

Answer (score 2):

In this case, char is just interpreted as a number and [| and ^ are the bitwise operators OR and XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B), respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The code just means:

```
while (*a != '\0' && *b != '\0')
   if (*a != *b)
```

The developer wanted to be clever using bitwise operators with the chars

Comment: a and b should be *a and *b, and the if is just *a != *b, not including the nul comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

That's the XOR operator, which means "exclusive OR".  It operates bitwise.

for each bit in your item:

0 ^ 0 = 0
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 0 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0

Answer (score 0):

| = Bitwise OR (inclusie OR)

^ = Bitwise XOR (exclusive OR)

Answer (score 0):

They will be treated as the binary representation. This typically means unsigned 1 byte. Not true for all architectures!

`(*a|*b)` means either `*a` or `*b` or both contain anything else than '\0'

`(*a^*b)` means that the two characters are not identical.

Comment: (*a|*b) means that BOTH of them don't equal 0, not either or.

Comment: Nope. (*a&*b) means both are nonzero. (*a|*b) means one or both are nonzero. 0|0==0, 0|1==1, 1|1==1